# generating Localizable.strings creates strange output

Tags: iphone, localization

When I use    `genstrings -o en.lproj *.m` it generates the Localizable.strings file with entries in this structure:

```
/* this is the text: %@  ID: %02X */

"this is the text: %@  ID: %02X" = "this is the text: %1$@  ID: %2$X";
```

Please notice that it makes from `%@ -> %1$@`

Why is this? I always have to change it back to `%@` manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the "-j" option? It produces java localized string (which have the format like %1$@).

[EDIT]

Sorry, looked at the wrong manual page. Please use the option `-noPositionalParameters` to turn off generation of positional parameters. -> [Info's here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/genstrings/osx-10.6.php)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change it back, since `%1$@` refers to the first argument given to your format string.

Actually, in a case different from yours, it might happen that the order of the arguments changes from a translation to another. For example, if your code uses a format to display some player property value like:

```
let fmt = NSLocalizedString("Player property value", comment: "The player property value")
String(format:fmt, playerName, playerProperty, value)
```

You might have in the "en.lproj/Localizable.strings":

```
/* The player property value */
"Player property value" = "Player %1$@'s %2$@ is %3$d"
```

and in the "fr.lproj/Localizable.strings":

```
/* The player property value */
"Player property value" = "Le %2$@ du joueur %1$@ is %3$d"
```

or:

```
/* The player property value */
"Player property value" = "Le joueur %1$@ a %3$d points de %2$@"
```